# Question Mark on symlink

Tags: linux, symlink

Why do I get a "?" mark at the end of a symlink sometimes?

E.g.

```
lrwxrwxrwx 2 root root 0 1969-12-31 19:00  xyz -> abc?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

More than likely there's a stray non-printing character at the end of the filename. Use `ls -lb` to show the character.